# How to calculate the modulus of 2x3 matrix

Tags: matrices

This may be a very basic question but I could not find a reasonable answer on the internet.
In Andrew NG Coursera course there are equations

[image]

I don't understand how this is being calculated. They have given the python function, but what is the math behind it?

So my main question is **how to calculate ||x|| here.**

Comment: By definition $\| (x_1, x_2, x_3)\| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$.

Comment: i get it. it was so easy. but i did not get the point. should i delete the question ?

Comment: I would not delete the question as maybe other people are having the same question.

Comment: @Steven01123581321 I agree, but sometimes people downvote easy questions. that discourage to ask again :P . Well, I don't delete it. I hope it will be useful for someone.

Comment: I upvoted it ;)

Comment: So nice of you :)